# C programming help, how to use the fopen and the fprintf functions in C to save the given output in a text file?

Tags: c, printf, fopen

Last time I worked on this code, it was working fine. I wanted the output to be saved into a text file (anything that is printed through `fprintf()`). Now, when I try to run the code again, it does not save the output in the given text file `draftday.txt`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{ 
    struct date
    {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };

    struct details
    {
        char name[50];
        int price;
        int code;
        int qty;
        struct date mfg;
    };

    struct details item[50];
    int n,i;

    getch();

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter number of items:");
    scanf("%d",&n);     

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Item name:");
        scanf("%[^\n]",item[i].name);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Item code:");
        scanf("%d",&item[i].code);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Quantity:");
        scanf("%d",&item[i].qty);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("price:");
        scanf("%d",&item[i].price);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Manufacturing date(dd-mm-yyyy):");
        scanf("%d-%d-%d",&item[i].mfg.day,&item[i].mfg.month,&item[i].mfg.year);
    }

    {
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=(fopen("draftday.txt","w"));
    if(fptr==NULL){
       printf("Error!");
       exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fptr,"             *****  INVENTORY *****\n\n\n"
                 "------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                 "S.N.|    NAME           |   CODE   |  QUANTITY |  PRICE  |MFG.DATE\n\n"
                 "------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");


    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        fprintf(fptr, "%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d       %d/%d/%d\n",i,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,
                item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: `<stdio.h>` and `<cstdlib>` together? who told you?

Comment: Cal `fclose(fptr)` at the end of your program.

Comment: idk, i am a newbie so expect these mistakes from me.

Comment: @barakmanos i did and still no luck

Comment: Did you read the documentation of these functions [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html), [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html), ... You should test their result!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i dont know about the setvbuf() but i have a little idea about the fopen() and fprintf()

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the `for` loop around:

```
        fprintf(fptr, "%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d     %d/%d/%d\n",i+1,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,
                item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);
```

Try:

```
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        fprintf(fptr, "%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d     %d/%d/%d\n",i+1,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,
                item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);
     }
```

Also, you are opening the output file in append mode. I am not sure you meant to do that. If not, change

```
fptr=(fopen("draftday.txt","a"));
```

to

```
fptr=(fopen("draftday.txt","w"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to notice here:

1. you're reading `n` number of items, but writing only the `n+1` th item, which is perfectly invalid.
2. you never checked for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the success.

To correct:

1. use the same `for`  loop condition you used to take the input.
2. don't forget to `fclose()` the file in the end.
3. Move the `fopen()` part outside the proposed `for` loop.

---

EDIT:

On linux, the below piece of code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct details
{
    char name[50];
    int price;
    int code;
    int qty;
    struct date mfg;
};


int main()
{

struct details item[50];
int n,i;

printf("Enter number of items:");
scanf("%d",&n);


for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    getchar();
    printf("Item name:");
    scanf("%[^\n]",item[i].name);


    printf("Item code:");
    scanf("%d",&item[i].code);


    printf("Quantity:");
    scanf("%d",&item[i].qty);


    printf("price:");
    scanf("%d",&item[i].price);


    printf("Manufacturing date(dd-mm-yyyy):");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d",&item[i].mfg.day,&item[i].mfg.month,&item[i].mfg.year);
}

{
FILE *fptr;
fptr=(fopen("draftday.txt","a"));
if(fptr==NULL){
   printf("Error!");
   exit(1);}

fprintf(fptr,"             *****  INVENTORY *****\n\n\n"
             "------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
             "S.N.|    NAME           |   CODE   |  QUANTITY |  PRICE  |MFG.DATE\n\n"
             "------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");


for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            fprintf(fptr, "%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d     %d/%d/%d\n",i+1,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,
              item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);

fclose(fptr);
}
}
```

Comment: i have edited the code, please check it out, though still not any luck

Comment: @MohammadQasim please avoid using `fflush(stdin);`. Its _mostly_ undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MohammadQasim well, it works for me !! i'm on linux. you can check a live and _slightly_ modified version of the code [here](http://goo.gl/Rw7Jvd)

Comment: @MohammadQasim It should . :-) BTW, this is the second time you're posting _almost_ same code, isn't it?

Comment: Yes :/ you could say that these are the troubles a newbie must go through

Comment: btw that tutorial point compiler is any good or not? i mean if i completely code on this particular compiler rather than my usual compiler (Microsoft visual studio), would there be any problem?

Comment: @MohammadQasim I understand, but do pay attention to the suggestions provided in the earlier answer. I can see you did not follow _all_ of them. :-) Best of luck, BTW.

Comment: @MohammadQasim I wanted to share the live code, that's why I've used some online compiler. Nevertheless, if the `gcc` version matches your requirement and you've got a working internet connectivity, there's no reason it (or any online compiler) should be bad.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help but come to think of it, another question arises. Why is this particular code not working on my Compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010) ? what could be the possible reasons for that?

Comment: @MohammadQasim Sorry, I'm kind of a `linux` `gcc` person. Not much knowledge in `(Microsoft Visual Studio 2010)` or others. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The data is not stored in the structure itself.
while storing the data in the file, you have to give the loop to store all the data from each position in the array.
only then the data will be taken from the position and stored in the file.

try this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {

            fprintf(fptr, "%d %-15s %-d %-5d %-5d %d/%d/%d\n",i+1,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,
                            item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);
```

}

if you want to clarify print the data in the structure.

Comment: i did that but still no luck.

Comment: just now executed your program and it is working perfectly. The data is stored in the file.

Comment: @sharon that is what i am saying, it was working fine a couple of days ago with me too now it is just not working.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S the main code is working but the text is not being stored on the text file

Comment: @MohammadQasim how could this be possible?

Comment: @sharon The file in which the data is stored, is it important that it should be stored in the project file or could it be placed anywhere?

Comment: @MohammadQasim the file will be created in the current directory. because you have not specified the path while opening the draftday.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your code. Try this.  Make sure that your file is in current directory. Or else give the full path name to that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    struct date
    {
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
    };

    struct details
    {
            char name[50];
            int price;
            int code;
            int qty;
            struct date mfg;
    };

    struct details item[50];
    int n,i;


    printf("Enter number of items:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=(fopen("draftday.txt","a"));
    if(fptr==NULL){
            printf("Error!");
            exit(1);}

    fprintf(fptr,"             *****  INVENTORY *****\n\n\n""------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n""S.N.|    NAME           |   CODE   |  QUANTITY |  PRICE  |MFG.DATE\n\n""------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            printf("Item name:");
            scanf(" %[^\n]",item[i].name);

            printf("Item code:");
            scanf(" %d",&item[i].code);

            printf("Quantity:");
            scanf(" %d",&item[i].qty);

            printf("price:");
            scanf(" %d",&item[i].price);

            printf("Manufacturing date(dd-mm-yyyy):");
            scanf(" %d-%d-%d",&item[i].mfg.day,&item[i].mfg.month,&item[i].mfg.year);


            fprintf(fptr, "%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d     %d/%d/%d\n",i+1,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);


    }
 }
```

Changes I did.

I store the data  After getting the input. for me it is working perfectly.